# Facebook login permission error

Tags: android, facebook, email, authentication

[image]I am trying to login with facebook in my android application and requsting these properties in my request

```
fbloginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends", "user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile", "contact_email");`
```

but i am getting an error can be seen in picture please suggest some solution.
Thanks

Comment: `setReadPermissions("public_profile email")` It will provide all details as you want except birthday.

Comment: that worked what if i want to get country and phone no as well ?

Comment: For security reason Facebook not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that there is no permission called `contact_email`. For getting the email of users, you need to use the `email` permission.

List of permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions